# Find Greatest Of Two Arrays And Store iN Third Array.?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++

!!
Hope You Guys Are At Good State Of Health .. 
On my side I'm trying to write code, which store the Greatest value.

Actually First I find Max Number between array1 and array2, Then store it in array3..
Yes, This Is Simple, But The Result Is Not Correct.. 
After Wasting Hours On It And Using Debugger, I still unable to track the problem.

I Hope You Guys Will Help Me .. 
Thanks For Your Consideration..

```
int max_hit(int *array1, int *array2, int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(*(array1+i) > *(array2+i))
        {
                    return *(array1+i);
        }
        else if(*(array2+i) > *(array1+i))
            {
                    return *(array2+i);
                }
    }

}

void fill_third(int *array1, int *array2, int *array3, int size)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        *(array3+j) = max_hit(array1, array2, size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use C style instead of normal array format?

Comment: Sir, My Instructor Say So.. Because we are learning pointers.. !!
BTW if I use normal array format, The error still exists.
As Array is actually a pointer, which is pointing to first element of array. . .

Comment: Provide some input, show what output your program produces, describe what output you expect.

Comment: Sort array1 and array2 and merge them into a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want to compare the elements in two arrays for each index and select the greater one into a third array. In this case, there is no need for the max_hit function, just use your favourite max function for each index.
For example:

```
void fill_third(int *array1, int *array2, int *array3, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        array3[i] = std::max(array1[i], array2[i]);
    }
}
```

Your max_hit function in the current form only selects the greater element at the first index where the two arrays' elements are not equal. Using this in fill_third will fill all elements of array3 with this number.

Comment: what would like to achieve with it?